# Running async code inside flatMap on Result type

Tags: swift

I have encountered an issue with the following code that fails to compile:

```
let message = Result { try decoder.decode(ConsumerMessage.self, from: payload) }
    .flatMap { (msg: ConsumerMessage) async in
        let analysed = await wa.doesContainViolentOrHarmfulMeaning(keywords: msg.interests)
        if (analysed) {
            return Result.failure(ConsumerError.harmfulOrViolentInterests("Interests contain harmful or violent meaning"))
        } else {
            return await redis.sadd(msg.interests, to: RedisKey(id)).get() != 0 ? Result.failure(ConsumerError.storeInterestsFailed("Failed to publish the interests")) : Result.success("Interests have been successfully published")
        }
    }
```

The compiler raises the following complaints:

> Cannot pass function of type `(ConsumerMessage) async -> Result<_, any Error>` to parameter expecting synchronous function type Generic
> parameter `NewSuccess` could not be inferred

How can I execute asynchronous code within the `flatMap` closure? I couldn't find an async variant in the documentation at
`https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/result/flatmap(_:)`.

Comment: There is nothing built int, but there is a nice Swift Package that gives `asyncFlatMap()` https://github.com/JohnSundell/CollectionConcurrencyKit/blob/main/Sources/CollectionConcurrencyKit.swift#L282

Answer (score 0):

Edited

```
  import Combine
    func checkForHarmfulContent(in keywords: [String]) -> Future<Bool, Error> {
    return Future { promise in
        // Perform the asynchronous operation here
        // Once the result is available, either fulfill or reject the promise
        let result = // Your async logic here
        
        if let error = result.error {
            promise(.failure(error))
        } else {
            promise(.success(result.value))
        }
    }
}

let message = Result { try decoder.decode(ConsumerMessage.self, from: payload) }
    .flatMap { (msg: ConsumerMessage) -> AnyPublisher<Result<String, ConsumerError>, Never> in
        return checkForHarmfulContent(in: msg.interests)
            .map { analyzed -> Result<String, ConsumerError> in
                if analyzed {
                    return .failure(ConsumerError.harmfulOrViolentInterests("Interests contain harmful or violent meaning"))
                } else {
                    return .success("Interests have been successfully published")
                }
            }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
```

Comment: I fear, your answer is incorrect. `FlatMap`'s closure requires to return a Publisher returned _synchronously_. This is also explicitly stated in the compiler error. In other words, you can't use an async function here. There are solutions for this problem though – an idiomatic one actually – which transforms an async function into a function returning a publisher.

Comment: maybe so now its corrected by the ai